# Show error message that is raised from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi, delphi-xe2

I use "Adoconnection" to connect to SQL Server and use below code in a ADOQuery :

```
BEGIN TRY
...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  RAISERROR(LTrim(str(ERROR_NUMBER())))
END CATCH
```

When I call error message by :       "AdoConnection.Errors[0].NativeError"
It always returns "5000"

and when I call error message by :   "AdoConnection.Errors[0].Number"
It returns a negative number!

How can I get right error number from SQL SERVER?

Answer (score 2):

All your own errors from MSSQL will have ERROR_NUMBER 50000. You CAN register your own messages using [sp_addmessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178649%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but using them is clumsy.

MSSQL 2012 have new keyword [THROW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx), which does exactly what you want.

So what you can do on 2008, assuming you recover from failure in CATCH block:

1. you can construct your own Error message, which will be in Exception.Message
2. ERROR_NUMBER is worthless
3. ERROR_SEVERITY severity is for different purposes
4. Hey, there is ERROR_STATE, you can use that :)
5. For stored procedures, you can use RETURN value or OUTPUT parameter for passing information about success or failure

```sql
BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRAN

  --
  -- some code
  --

  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 OR @SomeYourValue <> @SomeOtherValue
    RAISERROR('Your own error message', 16, 1);

  --
  -- some code
  --

  IF @@ROWCOUNT > 10 OR @SomeYourValue = @SomeOtherValue
    RAISERROR('Your own error message', 16, 2);

  COMMIT

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

  DECLARE
    @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(2048) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
    @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER(),
    @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE(),
    @ErrorProcedure NVARCHAR(126) = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
    @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE()

  ROLLBACK

  -- construct your own awesome message
  SET @ErrorMessage =
    LEFT(
        'Error ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(10)) + ': '
        + @ErrorMessage
        + ' Line: ' + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR(10))
        + ISNULL(' ' + @ErrorProcedure, ''), 2044)

  -- pass error
  RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)

  -- or use return value if you want numbers instead Error messages from SQL
  IF @ErrorNumber < 50000
    RETURN @ErrorNumber
  ELSE
    RETURN -@ErrorState
  -- In Delphi: AdoProc.Parameters.ParamByName('@RETURN_VALUE').AsInteger:
  -- 0 = all OK
  -- > 0 - some SQL error number
  -- < 0 - hey, my own errors!

  -- or declare @ErrorMessage, @ErrorNumber and @ErrorState as
  -- procedure's OUTPUT parameters
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I need to get an error number in Delphi. Is there any other solution?

Comment: It is in example code. You can use RETURN value or OUTPUT parameters - for stored procedures. Or you can "construct your own awesome" ErrorMessage and add ErrorNumber inside.